# How to set greater than - less than condition in Protege OWL/XML format

Tags: owl, protege

I want to add a restriction for height (data property) of a Person (class) such that height can't be <= 0.

Is there a data range / inequality value restriction in owl like:

`height only xsd:decimal[">0"^^xsd:decimal]`

As I understand, we have some xsd:minInclusive and xsd:maxExclusive conditions but unfortunately I don't know how to use it, in OWL reasoning.

Comment: your class expression looks close to what you need - but the facet itself should be before the literal, i.e. `height only xsd:decimal[> "0"^^xsd:decimal]`

Comment: @UninformedUser what if I want to restrict the age, let's say something like ```age only xsd:int[>"0"^^xsd:int <="272"xsd:int]``` this is not working

Comment: You need a comma to separate each constraint, e.g., `xsd:int[> 0,<= 272]`

Comment: Thanks, this worked ```age only xsd:int[>"0"^^xsd:int , <= "272"^^xsd:int]```